# How to fix a variable in my email link that is creating the wrong address?

Tags: javascript, html, magento2

The following code snippet in my magento 2 new order email template works fine when tested on my machine, but when customers click the hyperlink they're being directed to https://url4700.nexgenof.com/wf/

{{trans 'You can check the status of your order by logging into your account.' account_url=$this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/',[_nosid:1]) |raw}}

I'm trying to land customers on https://www.nexgenof.com/customer/account/ 
in this case, but instead of hardcoding the href string I need the store to be variable as eventually we'll be a multi-store site.

Comment: Is the text contained in the brackets the code snippet?

Comment: yes, including the brackets.  thank you!

Comment: In the emails that are sent to the customers is the hyperlink pointing to "https://url4700.nexgenof.com/wf/" or are they being redirected from "https://www.nexgenof.com/customer/account/" to "https://url4700.nexgenof.com/wf/".

Comment: when a customer hovers over the link the address it points to is the "url4700.nexgenof.com/wf".  No redirect.